# How to check files already uploaded in Uploadify JQ plugin?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, uploadify

I have to prevent users adding files which is already added in the server in 'uploadify' jquery plugin.

There is a grid which shows files which are already added, so I'm planning to get the files name collection from the grid and check it when on select function for preventing to add the already uploaded files.

Is there any better or easy way to do this?

Please help in finishing the code.

Will the above logic work ?

```
var uploadQueue = new Array();
jQuery().ready(function ($) {
 debugger;
            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 async: false,
                  url: ROOT + "Documents/DocumentAJAXController",
                 data: { "ID": $('[id="ID"]').val() },
                 success: function (result) {
                  }
            });

 $("#SubmitButton1").hide();
    $("#fileuploader").fileUpload({
            'uploader':  "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/FileUpload/uploader.swf")",
            'cancelImg':  "@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/clearBtn.png")",
            'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
            //'buttonImg' : "@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/attachDoc.png")",
            'script': "@Url.Content("~/Documents/Upload/")",   
            'folder': "@Url.Content("~/Documents/")",
            //'fileDesc': 'Documents Files',
            'fileExt': '*.pdf;*.doc;*.ppt;*.xls',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': false, 
            onError: function (a, b, c, d) {
            },
            'onSelect': function (event, queueID, fileObj) {

               // uploadQueue.push(queueID);

            },                
            'onAllComplete': function(event,data){
            alert("Uploaded successfully");
            $('.popupClose').click();
            }            
        });
```

Comment: You need to check (also) it server side. You can't rely client side validation for something like this. You shouldn't ask for us to "finish to code". We can help you but I'm not going to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is built into the latest version of uploadify.

Uploadify provides for a [checkScript handler](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/checkscript/) in the settings that you pass to uploadify.

If you point this at an appropriate server script it will not allow files that already exist.

A sample script called `check-exists.php` is provided in the uploadify zip.